# Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after connecting displayport

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse, display, hdmi

Just installed ubuntu 17.10, switching over from windows.
Everything seemed to be working fine until the installation is complete and I am inside ubuntu as suddenly the keyboard and mouse is unresponsive.

Tried rebooting and the issue remains.
Then I tried unplugging stuff and as soon as I unplugg the TV connected via a HDMI->DVI cable into a DVI->Displayport converter to my graphics card, it works. So I know that this seems like a lot of converting back and forth, but it did work in windows so I think it should work in ubuntu as well.

So does anyone have any idea of why it is not working when I have that plugged in?

Should be noted that I have to reboot after unplugging the TV

Comment: Can you edit your question to include details about your graphics card? I know that NVIDIA has had some problem with their drives of late.